# How to find only the name of a link?

Tags: filenames, symlink, c

Specifically, I need to write a C program where I put inside the pathname of a symbolic link and on output I print only the name of that symbolic link(not the name of the file pointed by the link). What functions and structures I must look at to find this information?

Comment: Can you explain this in more detail?  It sounds like you're saying you have the path of a symbolic link, and you want to print the name of that symbolic link - isn't that just "everything after the last / of the pathname" ?

Comment: I might not understand what you really want, and I am guessing you are misunderstanding how symlinks work. Please **edit your question** to improve it, e.g. give an example (or how you'll do that with commands, etc).

Comment: Could you define what is the name of a symbolic link? A symbolic link *is* (almost) a name....

Comment: Programming questions are off-topic here, you want [so]. But don't repost: your question is not worth asking, unless you meant something different from what you wrote. The name of the symbolic link is the name that you pass to the function.

Answer (score 2):

You can also look into readlinkat(..), it handles more error scenario's than readlink(..)

Comment: readlink and readlinkat are both useless, they open the link and read the name IN the link.

Answer (score 1):

It is operating system specific.

On Linux and POSIX, consider [`readlink`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/readlink.html) & [readlinkat](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/readlink.2.html) & [`lstat`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/lstat.html) (and [`stat`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/stat.html) for symlinks without existing targets) & [symlink](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/symlink.html) & [unlink](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/unlink.html) ...

Maybe [realpath(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/realpath.3.html) & [access(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/access.2.html) & `faccessat`  & [basename(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/basename.3.html) might be helpful to you.

Perhaps [POCO](http://pocoproject.org/) & Glib/GObject/GIO from [GTK](http://gtk.org/) are offering wrappers working on both Windows & POSIX.

Comment: readlink and readlinkat read the name IN the link, I don't need that, lstat give me a struct stat that contain only the information that that file is a link(st_mode), I need a way to obtain only the name of the link.